# CGImageRef gets corrupted after returned from a method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-graphics

My code creates an TIFFRepresentation of an image and I want to recode it to something different. This is not problematic.

My ImgUtils function is:

```
+ (CGImageRef) processImageData:(NSData*)rep {

    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:rep];

    int width = bitmapRep.size.width;
    int height = bitmapRep.size.height;
    size_t pixels_size = width * height;
    Byte raw_bytes[pixels_size * 3];

    //
    //  processing, creates and stores raw byte stream
    //

    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bytesPerPixel = 3;
    int bitsPerPixel = bytesPerPixel * bitsPerComponent;
    int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                              raw_bytes,
                                                              pixels_size * bytesPerPixel,
                                                              NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;

    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                        height,
                                        bitsPerComponent,
                                        bitsPerPixel,
                                        bytesPerRow,
                                        colorSpaceRef,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        NO,
                                        renderingIntent);


    [ImgUtils saveToPng:imageRef withSuffix:@"-ok"];

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    return imageRef;
}
```

There is another method, that saves a CGImageRef to filesystem.

```
+ (BOOL) saveToPng:(CGImageRef)imageRef withSuffix:(NSString*)suffix {
    CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Downloads/pic%@.png", suffix]];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, imageRef, nil);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
    CFRelease(destination);
    return YES;
}
```

As you can see, immediately after processing the image, I save it on a disk, as `pic-ok.png`.

Here is the code, that calls the processing function:

```
 CGImageRef cgImage = [ImgUtils processImageData:imageRep];
 [ImgUtils saveToPng:cgImage withSuffix:@"-bad"];
```

The problem is, that the two images differ. Second one, with the `-bad` suffix is corrupted.
See examples below. Seems like the memory area the CGImageRef pointer is pointing to is released and overwritten immediately after returning from the method.

[image: pic-ok.png]
[image: pic-bad.png]

I tried also `return CGImageCreateCopy(imageRef);` but it changed nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGDataProviderCreateWithData()` does not copy the buffer you provide. Its purpose is to allow creation of a data provider that accesses that buffer directly.

Your buffer is created on the stack. It goes invalid after `+processImageData:` returns. However, the CGImage still refers to the provider and the provider still refers to the now-invalid buffer.

One solution would be to create the buffer on the heap and provide a callback via the `releaseData` parameter that frees it. Another would be to create a `CFData` from the buffer (which copies it) and then create the data provider using `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData()`. Probably the best would be to create a `CFMutableData` of the desired capacity, set its length to match, and use its storage (`CFDataGetMutableBytePtr()`) as your buffer from the beginning. That's heap-allocated, memory-managed, and doesn't require any copying.

Comment: Great, thanks, missed this part. Also wrapped everything with a completion block and managed releasing myself.